# while loop blocks reading callbacks from gui

Tags: user-interface, while-loop, callback, scilab

I'm trying to add a stop button to a GUI which can be used to abort the gui and execution of a background while loop. Consider the code:

```
function pushFun(button)
    disp("Push!")
endfunction

h = figure(1);
set(h,'UserData',1);

button = uicontrol(h, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Stop',..
        'Position', [0 0 60 25], 'callback', 'pushFun',..
        "callback_type", 2);
```

which works perfectly fine. But the code:

```
function stopgui()
    global guistop;
    guistop = %t;
endfunction

h = figure(1);
set(h,'UserData',1);

global guistop
guistop = %f;

button = uicontrol(h, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Stop',..
        'Position', [0 0 60 25], 'callback', 'stopgui',..
        "callback_type", 2);

while ~guistop

    // some code here
    sleep(100)
end
```

does not respond to the pushbutton interactions. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is wrong and how I can solve it.

**P.S.** similar discussions: [one](https://www.reddit.com/r/numerical/comments/6r46jo/how_to_wait_for_button_callback_in_a_while_loop/), [two](http://mailinglists.scilab.org/scilab-6-0-0-beta-1-2-uicontrol-callback-problem-td4034221.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use callback type 10 (prioritary (or non-interruptible) Scilab instructions):

```
button = uicontrol(h, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Stop',..
                   'Position', [0 0 60 25], 'callback', 'stopgui',..
                   'callback_type', 10);
```